# How to avoid a draggable element to be dropped in a certain sortable location in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, sortablejs

I have a page where two drag and drop functionalities are working. Suppose A and B are draggable components and C and D are droppable regions. But I have to restrict A being dropped in location D which is currently happening in my site. How to avoid it using sortable widget in jquery?

Sortable.create() method is used here.

Comment: if you can add your code snippet then it will be more easy to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict it with id or class selector just put a condition if a certain draggable item comes in non required dropable region don't call the draggable function just restrict this event and show some info message accordingly.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?